# Subtitle program to synchronize the subtitle with video

Tags: windows, video, closed-captions

A lot of times when I search over the internet for a subtitle to a movie, I get many results, but sometimes the subtitle I get isn't suitable to the movie format.

For example: movie in Blu-ray and the only subtitle that exists is for DVD.

I want to ask about the best subtitle software to synchronize the subtitle easily with a specific video.

Comment: Hm, what's "the best" for the cat doesn't necessarily fit the mouse. What criteria shall we apply to determine "best" here? Any price tag? Must it search "the interwebs" for matching subtitles (maybe some of the subtitle-specific sites are more important for you than others – languages might matter here as well as the region the BD/DVDs are from)? What might be the work-flow you'd find fitting? Please also take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then [edit] your question with some more details. Tnx!

Comment: At least you need to specify the format of the video file and the subtitle file you are trying to sync. Also, if the video of the blue ray and DVD versions are edited differently or the same.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Subtitle Workshop.](http://subworkshop.sourceforge.net/)

Also, you could just use Media Player Classic HC following [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/573450/162573).